# Spring CommonsMultipartResolver always return null for the MultipartFile

Tags: spring, multipart

If I use `StandardServletMultipartResolver`, I get the file properly, but if I use `CommonsMultipartResolver` I get null for the file. Even without any additional configuration, just replacing `new StandardServletMultipartResolver();` with `new CommonsMultipartResolver();` the files are not received. I wanted to enforce `maxUploadSizePerFile` and hence used `CommonsMultipartResolver`.

In my WebContext Configuration file, I have the following:

```
@Override
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    Long maxFileSize = environment.getRequiredProperty(PropertyConstants.MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE, Long.class);
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(maxFileSize);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

If I just replace the `CommonsMultipartResolver` with `StandardServletMultipartResolver`, things start to work. I have `commons-fileupload` in mvn dependency and the application gets launched without any error.

I am using Tomcat 9.0.0.M1 and Spring 4.2.2.

Is there some configuration I am missing for `CommonsMultipartResolver` to work?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue. I need the CommonsMultipartResolver  because I need to set the encoding to utf-8

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, but I note that it only occurs when `CommonsFileUploadSupport` stores the file in memory.  As a workaround I found setting `maxInMemorySize` to `0` works e.g.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->
    <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <!-- oddly, the MultipartFile passed as a RequestParam gets set to null if I allow it to use memory 
        rather than disk!  -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="0" /> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Servers repertory and Try to add `allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"` in the context.xml of Tomcat Server in your workspace project.